# Converting epoch time to date format

Tags: epoch

I'm saving *seconds since epoch* in an `unsigned long long` type. how can I know what is the latest date I can get? And is there another type (besides `unsigned long long`) what allows me to express an even later date?

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned long long` is only guaranteed to be [*at least* 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5836380/50447), so your maximum end date is *at least* 2^64 seconds after the start of your epoch (approx, 2.13503982E14 days).

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you mean the C++ language

An unsigned long long will be at least 8 bytes (= 64 bits) large. So the range is from 0 to 2^64. You simply need to determine the date of 2^64; the underlying operating system should provide you with enough to do that.

For your second question - let me answer it like this: You can get a type to store an 'infinite' amount of bytes; 'infinite' means as much memory as available to you. Such a type would be like the BigInteger type from Java. Here is a question that addresses exactly that issue:

[Big numbers library in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988099/big-numbers-library-in-c)