# Length of a C++ std::string in bytes

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

I'm having some trouble figuring out the exact semantics of `std::string.length()`.
The [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/) explicitly points out that `length()` returns the number of characters in the string and *not* the number of bytes. I was wondering in which cases this actually makes a difference.

In particular, is this only relevant to non-char instantiations of `std::basic_string<>` or can I also get into trouble when storing UTF-8 strings with multi-byte characters? Does the standard allow for `length()` to be UTF8-aware?

Comment: there is wstring for UTF and there it makes senses that length returns the number of characters since the character's size could vary.

Comment: @AndersK.: No, `wchar_t` has a fixed size like any other type. It can't magically vary.

Comment: Also check this lovely thread about `std::string` vs. `std::wstring` and some stuff about Unicode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring

Comment: @AndersK.: `wstring` has nothing to do with UTF. Perhaps you were thinking of `u16string` or `u32string`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When dealing with non-`char` instantiations of `std::basic_string<>`, sure, length may not equal number of bytes. This is particularly evident with `std::wstring`:

```
std::wstring ws = L"hi";
cout << ws.length();     // <-- 2, not 4
```

But `std::string` is about `char` characters; there is no such thing as a multi-byte character as far as `std::string` is concerned, whether you crammed one in at a high level or not. So, `std::string.length()` is always the number of bytes represented by the string. Note that if you're cramming multibyte "characters" into an `std::string`, then your definition of "character" suddenly becomes at odds with that of the container and of the standard.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I simply got confused by the wording in the documentation here. Thanks for clearing things up.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: Not a problem :)

Comment: *But `std::string` is about `char` characters*, so the definition of "character" in C++ is "element of some string type", rather than "what a human sees, encoded" or "a unicode codepoint, encoded somehow".  This sounds believable, but can anyone quote chapter-and-verse on this?

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala: It's less that the standard says it doesn't care about encodings, and more about it not saying that it does. Still, `2.3/1` might be of interest - it defines the "basic character set". And `2.3/3` says: `The execution character set
and the execution wide-character set are implementation-defined supersets of the basic execution character set and the basic execution wide-character set, respectively. The values of the members of the execution character sets and the sets of additional members are locale-specific.`

Comment: Well, I guess that's what I get for asking for chapter-and-verse.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala: Yes, when asking for chapter-and-verse, you get chapter-and-verse. Anything else I can help you with? :)

Answer (score 12):

If we are talking specifically about `std::string`, then `length()` **does** return the number of bytes.

This is because a `std::string` is a `basic_string` of `char`s, and the C++ Standard defines the size of one `char` to be exactly one byte.

Note that the Standard doesn't say how many bits are in a byte, but that's another story entirely and you probably don't care.

EDIT:  The Standard does say that an implementation shall provide a definition for `CHAR_BIT` which says how many bits are in a byte.

By the way, if you go down a road where you do care how many bits are in a byte, you might consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4329777/241536).

Comment: Indeed, "byte" is not necessarily synonymous with "octet".

Comment: The standard does define `CHAR_BIT`, the number of bits in a byte.

Comment: @Mike:  True, but the Standard doesn't say what that's defined to.  When I said "doesn't say how many bits are in a byte" I meant in a precise, unambigious sense.  But I'll clarify my post with an edit, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4):

A `std::string` is `std::basic_string<char>`, so `s.length() * sizeof(char) = byte length`. Also, `std::string` knows nothing of UTF-8, so you're going to get the byte size even if that's not really what you're after.

If you have UTF-8 data in a `std::string`, you'll need to use something else such as [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) to get the "real" length.

Answer (score 0):

cplusplus.com is not "the documentation" for `std::string`, it's a poor quality site full of poor quality information. The C++ standard defines it very clearly:

- 21.1 [strings.general] ¶1

  > This Clause describes components for manipulating sequences of any non-array POD (3.9) type. In this Clause such types are called *char-like types*, and objects of char-like types are called *char-like objects* or simply *characters*.
- 21.4.4 [string.capacity] ¶1

  > `size_type size() const noexcept;`
  >   *Returns:* A count of the number of char-like objects currently in the string.
  >   *Complexity:* constant time.
  >
  > `size_type length() const noexcept;`
  >   *Returns:* `size()`