# Why a pointer to an integer increments by 4 bytes?

Tags: c++, c, memory, pointers, increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about pointer increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610298/question-about-pointer-increment)

When i increment a int pointer then its address have a gap of 4 bytes. why it is so ? why a int pointer takes 4 bytes to store whereas a char takes 2 bytes ?

Comment: Please show us the code from which you conclude that a `char` takes 2 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

When you increment a pointer of a type A, you *move* that pointer forward in the memory by the size of the type it points to. On your machine, int takes 4 bytes, so the pointer moves by 4 bytes.

As for "why does `int` take 4 bytes on my machine?":

The C++ standard says (4.9.1. paragraph 2):

> There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short
> int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long long int”. In this list, each type
> provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list.
> <...> Plain ints have the natural size suggested by the architecture
> of the execution environment<sup>[44]</sup>; the other signed integer types are
> provided to meet special needs.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>[44]</sup>: that is, large enough to contain any value in the
> range of INT_MIN and INT_MAX, as defined in the header .

Basically, the sizes of fundamental types are not set in stone, and are implementation-defined. The accepted answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398630/why-are-c-int-and-long-types-both-4-bytes) has some information about it.

Comment: thats what m asking , why it takes 4 bytes not 5 or 6 ?

Answer (score 2):

the size of the pointer to any data types always be the same as supported by your system

If system is 32 -bit the size would be 4 bytes for all the pointers.

In pointer arithmetic when you do `ptr++` or `ptr--` the increments and decrements takes place according to the size of the data type this `ptr`pointer points to .

```
char *cptr;
int *iptr;
char c[5];
int a[5];
cptr=c;
iptr=a;
```

By doing `cptr++` you will get `c[1]` and pointer will increments by only one byte 
You can check the address of each char.

Similarly `iptr++` will give you `a[1]` here pointer increased by 4 bytes.

```
int main()
{
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
  printf("%p\t",&c[i]); //internally pointer arithmeitc: (c+sizeof(char)*i) , 
  printf("%p\n",&a[i]); //intenally pointer arithmetic : (a+sizeof(int)*i)
 }
}
```

Size of `int` or other data types are implementation defined

Comment: Strictly speaking, not necessarily all the pointers. There can be other pointer systems not related to the bit size of the system...

Comment: thats what m asking , why it takes 4 bytes not 5 or 6 ?

Comment: @l4zyw0rm: pointer arithmetic takes place like this so it is

Answer (score 2):

Here is the general rule:

- If the type is `T`, its size `N` is calculated as `sizeof(T)` bytes. So pointer of type `T*` is increased by `N` bytes if you increment the pointer by `1`.

  Mathematically,

  ```
  T  *p = getT();

  size_t diff = static_cast<size_t>(p+1) - static_cast<size_t>(p);

  bool alwaysTrue = (diff == sizeof(T)); //alwaysTrue is always true!
  ```

Answer (score 1):

because the size of data (int) which the pointer is pointing has 4 byte size so the pointer increments 4 bytes (size of data (int))

another example: if you have structure with size 8 byte and you have pointer pointing to this structure the increment of this pointer will be 8 byte:

```
struct test {
   int x;
   int y;
}

struct test ARRAY[50];
struct test *p=ARRAY; // p pointer is pointing here to the first element ARRAY[0]. ARRAY[0] is with size 8 bytes

p++; // this will increment p with 8 byte (size of struct test). So p now is pointing to the second element ARRAY[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointers increment by the size in bytes of the things they point to. ints take 4 bytes on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: thats what m asking , why it takes 4 bytes not 5 or 6 ?

Comment: By definition. A byte is 8 bits. 8 times 4 = 32. On a machine with 32-bit integers, an int takes 4 bytes.

Comment: @Matthew'Cogwheel'Orlando, Usually, that is. It can technically be a different number of bits than 8.

Comment: what about in 64-bit machine

Answer (score 1):

Because, on your computer, `sizeof (int) == 4`, so stepping from one `int` to the next requires an increment of four bytes.

Most integer types have different sizes on different computers. `int` must have at least 16 bits, and is supposed to be a "natural" size for the computer. Most 32 or 64-bit platforms choose 32 bits as a "natural" size, and most computers have 8-bit bytes, so 4 bytes is a very common size for `int`.

However, `sizeof (char) == 1` on all computers, so I'm rather surprised that you say "a char takes 2 bytes". It should only take one.