# Int types in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, 64-bit, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are C++ int and long types both 4 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398630/why-are-c-int-and-long-types-both-4-bytes)

In C/C++, what is the difference between:

```
u_int64 myNum;
```

and:

```
unsigned long myNum;
```

As far as I can tell, both ate just unsigned integers, with 64bits of memory.

Comment: `unsigned long` is >= 32 bits.

Comment: `long` only has to be at least as long as `int`

Comment: Really? Wow, I thought it was 64. In java it is 64, is it not?

Comment: @ChristianDaley `long` is at least 32-bit and `int` is at least 16-bit

Comment: In Java, `long` does mean signed 64 bit, but not neccessarily so in C.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_variable_types_and_declarations#Size provides a nice summary.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738568/any-guaranteed-minimum-sizes-for-types-in-c .

Answer (score 8):

`unsigned long` does not *have* to be 64 bits, whereas `uint64_t` does. There is a kind of hierarchy of integer types where each type has to be at least large as the preceding type: `signed char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`, and similarly for their unsigned counterparts. There are some anchor points, stating that `char` is one byte (a byte does not have to be 8 bits, as far as I can recall `short` is at least <strike>2 bytes</strike> 16 bits. In C++11, [long long is at least 64 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053113/is-c11s-long-long-really-at-least-64-bits). But none of these types is *exactly* a given number of bits.

See [fixed width integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) for more information (thanks to @chris for the link).

Comment: So if I want a number that is always 64bit, I should use u_int64

Comment: @ChristianDaley, See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). It might help you.

Comment: @ChristianDaley Do you mean `uint64_t`? If so, yes. However, the type may not exist if your platform does not provide a 64 bit type. There's always `uint_least64_t` which will provide the first type that has at least 64 bits.

Comment: Your hierarchy should begin with `signed char`. The naked `char` is a bit of an odd one out.

Comment: It's entirely feasible for `short` to be only one byte long. In fact, you can have `sizeof(char) == sizeof(short) == sizeof(int) == 1`, as long as a `char` is wide enough.

Comment: @KerrekSB thanks for the `signed char` correction. Concerning `short`, could it be that it is "at least 16 bits", not two bytes? O rmaybe I dreamt the whole thing up.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Right, `short` needs at least 16 bits.

Comment: `There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long
long int”. In this list, each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list.` - § 3.9.1

Answer (score 0):

The C language itself doesn't specify how big an `int` is

`long` only has to be at least as long as `int`
`long long` only has to be at least as long as `long`

also `u_int64_t` is a c99 type, and wouldn't be available in ANSI c89.

also among 64 bit architectures that are differences LP64 indicates `long`'s and pointers are 64 bit, LLP64 means that `long long`'s and pointers are 64 bit.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Would I be able to use u_int64 in Xcode?

Comment: C has no `u_int64` type. C has an optional `uint64_t` type.

Comment: yeah any version of xcode that you could find on apple's site will have a c99 compliant compiler included.

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned long` is dependent on the machine like every `int` in C/C++. Many library especially libraries that allow for two machines to interact will type def most `int` like numbers to make sure both are the same size. `u_int64` is basically type def to an unsigned integer of 64 bits, to allow for use on any machine. In theory `unsigned long` could be 128, 64, 256 or pretty much any size.