# int limit vs long limit

Tags: c++, int, long-integer

Everyone knows this, `int` are smaller than `long`.

Behind [this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/296az74e.aspx), I'm reading the following :

```
INT_MIN (Minimum value for a variable of type int.)    –2147483648
INT_MAX (Maximum value for a variable of type int.)     2147483647

LONG_MIN (Minimum value for a variable of type long.)  –2147483648
LONG_MAX (Maximum value for a variable of type long.)   2147483647
```

The same information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx).

Have I been told a lie my whole life? What is the difference between `int` and `long` if not the values they can hold ? How come?

Comment: Both of those limits refer to C++, not C#

Comment: That's C++, not C#, see the breadcrums on that page: `... C++ Language > Reference Fundamental Types > Numerical Limits`

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx for C#

Comment: See this question if you're interested in the difference in C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c

Comment: Woops you're right, editing now !

Comment: [Why are C++ int and long types both 4 bytes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13398630/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mentioned both C++ and ASP.NET. The two are very different.

As far as the C and C++ specifications are concerned, the only thing you know about a primitive data type is the maximal range of values it can store. Prepare for your first surprise - `int` corresponds to a range of [-32767; 32767]. Most people today think that `int` is a 32-bit number, but it's really only guaranteed to be able to store the equivallent of a 16-bit number, almost. Also note that the range isn't the more typical [-32768; 32767], because C was designed as a common abstract machine for a wide range of platforms, including platforms that didn't use 2's complement for their negative numbers.

It shouldn't therefore be surprising that `long` is actually a "sort-of-32-bit" data type. This doesn't mean that C++ implementations on Linux (which commonly use a 64-bit number for `long`) are wrong, but it does mean that C++ applications written for Linux that assume that `long` is 64-bit *are* wrong. This is a lot of fun when porting C++ applications to Windows, of course.

The standard 64-bittish integer type to use is `long long`, and that is the standard way of declaring a 64-bittish integer on Windows.

However, .NET cares about no such things, because it is built from the ground up on its own specification - in part exactly because of how history-laden C and C++ are. In .NET, `int` is a 32-bit integer, and `long` is a 64-bit integer, and `long` is *always* bigger than `int`. In C, if you used `long` (32-bittish) and stored a value like ten trillion in there, there was a chance it would work, since it's possible that your `long` was actually a 64-bit number, and C didn't care about the distinction - that's exactly what happens on most Linux C and C++ compilers. Since the types are defined like this for performance reasons, it's perfectly legal for the compiler to use a 32-bit data type to store a 8-bit value (keep that in mind when you're "optimizing for performance" - the compiler is doing optimizations of its own). .NET can still run on platforms that don't have e.g. 32-bit 2's complement integers, but the runtime must ensure that the type can hold as much as a 32-bit 2's complement integer, even if that means taking the next bigger type ("wasting" twice as much memory, usually).

Comment: on 32-bit Linux `long` is also 32 bits

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc It ultimately depends on the compiler - I'm not sure which compilers do it in what way, but all the Linux-borne code I've worked with assumed `long` can hold a 64-bit value (on a 64-bit OS and CPU, that is).

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++ the requirements are that `int` can hold at least 16 bits, `long` can hold at least 32 bits, and `int` can not be larger than `long`. There is no requirement that `int` be smaller than `long`, although compilers often implement them that way. You haven't been told a lie, but you've been told an oversimplification.

Comment: Yeah, there's a thin line between "lie" and "oversimplification". Smart people lie by oversimplifying :P

Answer (score 1):

This is C++

> On many (but not all) C and C++ implementations, a long is larger than
>   an int. Today's most popular desktop platforms, such as Windows and
>   Linux, run primarily on 32 bit processors and most compilers for these
>   platforms use a 32 bit int which has the same size and representation
>   as a long.

See the ref http://tsemba.org/c/inttypes.html

Answer (score 1):

**No!** Well! Its like, we had been told since childhood, that sun rises in the east and sets in the west. (the Sun doesn't move after all! )

In earlier processing environments, where we had **16 bit Operating Systems**, an integer was considered to be of 16 bits(2 bytes), and a 'long' as 4 bytes (32 bits)

But, with the advent of **32 bit and 64 bit OS**, an integer is said to consist of 32 bits(4 bytes) and a long to be '**atleast as big** as an integer', hence, 32 bits again. Thereby explaining the equality between the maximum and minimum ranges 'int' and 'long' can take.

Hence, this depends entirely on the **architecture** of your system.