# How wide are ints

Tags: c++, c++11

I vaguely remember reading a section in the C++ standard that stated the minimum width requirements for integer types.  I cannot find this any more.  The closest I can find is the description of `<limits.h>` in the C standard.

Where would I find the minimum widths of integer types?

Comment: If you're actually looking to use the size of these types in your code, I'd suggest using the exact sized types in stdint or in Boost.Integer. They are able to make cross platform guarantees about the sizes of the types they represent. If you just want to know for the sake of knowing, it varies by compiler.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4337544/902497) to [Is \`long\` guaranteed to be at least 32 bits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329777/is-long-guaranteed-to-be-at-least-32-bits) gives the minimum required ranges for integer types. For `int`, the minimum range is `-32767` to `+32767` (5.2.4.2.1).

Answer (score 2):

The minimum range requirements defined in standard are (3.9.1 - Fundamental Types):

> Objects declared as characters (char) shall be large enough to store any member of the implementation’s basic
>   character set.

and

> There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long
>   long int”. In this list, each type provides **at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list.**
>   There may also be implementation-defined extended signed integer types. The standard and extended signed
>   integer types are collectively called signed integer types. **Plain ints have the natural size suggested by the
>   architecture of the execution environment**<sup>44</sup>; the other signed integer types are provided to meet special
>   needs.

Footnote 44 on this page says:

> 44) that is, large enough to contain any value in the range of INT_MIN and INT_MAX, as defined in the header `<climits>`.

And C standard in 5.2.4.2.1 says:

```
// minimum value for an object of type int
INT_MIN -32767 // −(215 − 1)
// — maximum value for an object of type int
INT_MAX +32767 // 215 − 1
```

Comment: No, those are not the only guarantees.  There are minimum range requirements (which imply minimum size requirements) for each type.

Comment: Where are the range requirements documented?

Comment: @Graznarak 3.9.1 - Fundamental types

Comment: @Graznarak: The specific minimum range requirements do not exist in the C++ standard. They are little more than a footnote reference to the `<limits.h>` header and the C99 standard, which seems to imply a suggested range, not a hard requirement.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric 3.9.1 only specifies relative sizes.  I want to know where the minimum sizes for each integer type are specified.

Comment: @greyfade: The document says *"Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown ..."* -- I don't see how that can be read as not being a requirement.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: The "soft requirement" I'm talking about is the contents of `limits.h`, since it's a loose reference to the C99 standard.