# Converting network byte order (big endian) to little endian

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winsock, endianness

I have found the following function from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which converts an `unsigned long` from network byte to `unsigned long` in host byte order i.e. in little-endian defined as:

```
u_long WSAAPI ntohl(
       _In_  u_long netlong
);
```

The MSDN document says that it can convert a 32 bits number. But since in C++ as I have read that `long` and `int` are not the same i.e. `long` is not guaranteed to be 32 bits or the same size of an integer `INT_MAX`.

So, I wonder if there is a a similar function which takes a 32 bits values such as `unsigned int` instead of `unsigned long`?

Comment: `long` and `u_long` are 32bit on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) specifically says that `ntohl`'s `netlong` parameter is a 32-bit value:

### netlong [in]

> A 32-bit number in TCP/IP network byte order.

---

> I have read that long and int are not the same i.e. long is not
>   guaranteed to be 32 bits or the same size of an integer INT_MAX.

You're right -- in *Standard C++* a `long` is [not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329777/is-long-guaranteed-to-be-at-least-32-bits) to be any particular size, except that it must be *at least* 32 bits.

However since we're talking about the endian conversion functions, we're talking about platform-specifics here.  We need to drill down now in to what a `long` is *under Windows*.  And under Windows, a long [is 32-bits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

### LONG

> A 32-bit signed integer. The range is –2147483648 through 2147483647
>   decimal. This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:

```
typedef long LONG;
```

Comment: Does this mean that if I pass `u_int` to the function it will be fine? Because the function accepts `u_long` as input which may or may not be 32 bits.

Comment: @cpx:  Under Windows, an `int` is also a 32-bit integer.  See the documentation I linked.

Answer (score 0):

`ntohl()` and `htonl()` always operate on 32-bit values on all platforms.  That is part of the BSD standard.  On platforms where `(u_)long` is larger than 32-bits, a different 32-bit data type will be used instead.  For instance, some platforms, including Linux and FreeBSD, use `uint32_t` to avoid any issues with the size of `(u_)long`.